# Referencing DLL from one project in another in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012

I am a newbie to Visual Studio and am trying to reference a dll of one project from another in the same solution.  I've added references, specified project dependencies and managed to reference header files within the code but when I build the solution I get errors similar to the following:

```
unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl increment(int)"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, dependencies to native DLL projects are not automatic in VisualStudio.

But you can add the dependency manually. When you compile the DLL it will actually build a `.dll` file and a `.lib` file. So in the properties of the project that uses the library, go to *Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies* and add the name of the `.lib` file.

Remember that, for the `increment()` function to work properly, you have to declare it as `__declspec(dllexport)` when compiling it in the DLL. And it is usually a good idea to compile it as `__declspec(dllimport)` when used in the client program. It is customary to use some macros to share the same `.h` file.