# Use gtest to write unit tests for a dynamic library

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I am new to gtest and gmock but certainly finding it useful. Currently I have built gtest and wrote sample test cases and executed them to see a proper workflow of gtest.

As in my main usecase the library I want to unit test is a dll (dynamic linking library). Until now I have created the project as static library and and wrote unit test cases for the same and it works fine but when I build it as dll, visual studio gives me linker error while trying to find `Calculator.lib`. Shouldn't it find `Calculator.dll` in this case.

Why it is going to find the `.lib` ?I wonder how can I load dll to write unit test cases for ?

I am new to it, please pardon me for stupid question.

Comment: How did you build the dll? You can make it generate a lib file. How do you "link" the dll to the project?

Comment: I changed the configuration type to dll and voila ! its done ! and the linking part, how do I do it ? I am not sure, and that's what the question is @doctorlove

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668224/referencing-dll-from-one-project-in-another-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: Ye it does, Thanks ! The problem is I cannot find the .lib file corresponding to the .dll, of course I can see the .obj but no .lib. How do I generate the .lib along with .dll ? @doctorlove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulling together the comments,

[image: export symbols]

when you make the dll.

When you build the `dll` you will also get a `lib` file.

Then as you can use Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies and add the name of the .lib file.

This will pick up the exported symbols: make sure you actually export things to use them.

Comment: Works Well ! Thanks !

Comment: In this approach, should we copy the DLL file to the bin path of UnitTest project?

Comment: That should work, or you make sure it's on the PATH